# Postgres doesn't store system time in the database

Tags: postgresql, django-models, docker-compose, python-datetime, django-timezone

I am using docker-compose for a registration form, where the api and database reside in separate containers.
The response on registration shows system date and time, which I wanted, but  in postgres date field shows incorrect data, and I don't know which time format it is using. The code was written in python with Django framework.Please help me in this.
Following is the postman response:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "msg": "Registration Success",
    "details": {
      "email": "test22@gmail.com",
      "mobile_num": "5698745210",
      "date_joined": "2020-06-27T14:43:28.329284",
      "user_type": [
         "Companion",
         "Community"
       ],
      "otp_verified": false
     }
}
```

Here the **date_joined** field picks system datetime, which is not my concern, but in postgres database, data is like this:

```
 2020-06-27 09:13:28.329284+00
```

The time of registration was 2:30 pm, but postgres shows 9:13.
The source code of model is here:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
  user_type = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 20))
  mobile_num = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
  otp_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Also whenever I re-build a container, docker shows the log as:

```
django_app_1     | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField User.date_joined received a naive datetime (2020-06-27 14:43:28.329284) while time zone support is active.
django_app_1     |   RuntimeWarning)
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well you evaluate `now()` when the server starts, so it will each time add the time when the server started as default value. You can pass a callable instead, for example with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class User(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    user_type = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20))
    mobile_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    otp_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here we thus do *not* pass a `datetime` object, but a function that will *generate* a `datetime` object.

It is however better to make use of the [**`auto_now_add=True`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) instead:

```
class User(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_type = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20))
    mobile_num = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    otp_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```